# Why doesn't target destination in Testdisk have a directory tree?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk

I was using Testdisk in K oppix but I'm sure this applies to Ubuntu.

I can find files on the bad partition using the directory tree.   I hit c to copy the file and then Testdisk wants the destination folder.

Every example video or instruction page says I should be seeing a direcotry tree on my destination drive.   I don't but the destination drive shows its mounted.

Comment: This is askUbuntu, have you tried it on Ubuntu? Is it at least the same version of testdisk that Ubuntu has? And when you *"hit c to copy the file and then Testdisk wants the destination folder"* it sounds like the directory tree you're looking for... what do you think you're missing? (PS you can copy & paste testdisk's output, it's just text, and edit it into your question as code)

Comment: Thank you but according to video instructions I've seen on Youtube for Testdisk, the destination folder shows root level and you can go down the directory tree to choose a folder.

Comment: Moving up a directory should work by "selecting" the `..` entry, running as root you should have no limits. But without seeing the video or a screenshot I'm not sure what they're doing, possibly they have some custom "save file" dialog?

Comment: Thank you.  I know how to navigate but the issue seems to be there's no mount point.  I've installed Ubuntu and downloaded the Testdisk and extracted to a folder.   According to instructions for installing packages I should see an Install file for directions.  I don't.   Sudo apt-get install testdisk doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm not sure where testdisk is looking, but it should be able to browser right from your root directory to anywhere (if it's running as root/sudo), and it usually only targets devices for working on, not mountpoints, maybe that's the problem? (apt-get should definitely install testdisk, it's [in ubuntu's universe repo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/testdisk), maybe universe isn't enabled)

Comment: Thanks to all for your responses.  Once I figured out how to install the package from a download into a folder, all worked extremely well.   It's been at least 15 years since I've used Linux.  Lots of cobwebs!!

Comment: How do I mark my question as SOLVED?

Comment: Selecting an answer as "correct" (clicking the check mark to green) solves a question, I've posted my last comment as a hopefully helpful answer so if it helped you could select it? - I had no idea how to install things when I first ran linux, that should be in a welcome splash screen (it's in help pages on the web but who wants to read through all those ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where testdisk is looking, but it should be able to browse right from your root directory to anywhere (if it's running as root/sudo), and it usually only targets devices for working on, not mountpoints, maybe that's the problem?

`apt-get` should definitely install testdisk, it's in ubuntu's universe repository, maybe universe isn't enabled in your sources so it's not showing up? `dpkg -i` can install downloaded .deb files too, though usually apt is easier / safer.